# Adding Post id to the end of slug in a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, slug

I have created a Custom Post Type (jobs) - Functions fine. But due to the possibility of duplicate page titles by admin, I need the permalink/slug to include the Post_ID to the end of the Post title, to make it unique, not a new directory but add -id to page title. I have investigated several options. This seems to look the cleanest and simplest addition to my standard post type registration code.

The below code has been added to my Post type registration code, makes the frontend links correct [www.domain.com/jobs/postname-postid](http://www.domain.com/jobs/postname-postid) ([www.domain.com/jobs/**accountant**-**123**](http://www.domain.com/jobs/**accountant**-**123**)). However, the rewrite element after, is not working as I get a 404. I'm also concerned about any negative/good practice impact of this on other functions/seo. But it does look quite standard and security safe. Help greatly appreciated.

```
function mycustomname_links($post_link, $post = 0) {
    if($post->post_type === 'listings') {
        return home_url('jobs/' .$post->post_name . '-' .$post->ID);
    }
    else{
        return $post_link;
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mycustomname_links', 1, 3);
```

***Rewrite element***

```
function mycustomname_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule('jobs/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=listings&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init');
```

Full Code

```
//callback
function lt_register_listing_type() {
    
// Labels array - where labels go.
    
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => __( 'Job Listings', LTDOMAIN ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Job Listing', LTDOMAIN ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Recruiter Logo', LTDOMAIN ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set Recruiter Logo', LTDOMAIN ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove Recruiter Logo', LTDOMAIN ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use Recruiter Logo', LTDOMAIN ),
        'archives' => __( 'Job Archive', LTDOMAIN ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New Job Listing', LTDOMAIN ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Job Item', LTDOMAIN ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Job Listing', LTDOMAIN ),
    );
    
// arguments array
    
    $args = array( 
        'label' => __( 'Job Listings', LTDOMAIN  ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-document',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        // 'rewrite' => array( 'has_front' => true ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'jobs'  ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'trackbacks', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ],
        'taxonomies' => [ 'category', 'post_tag' ],
        'show_in_rest' => true,
);
    register_post_type( 'listings', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'lt_register_listing_type' );

//Front end link change

function mycustomname_links($post_link, $post = 0) {
    if($post->post_type === 'listings') {
        return home_url('jobs/' .$post->post_name . '-' .$post->ID);
    }
    else{
        return $post_link;
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mycustomname_links', 1, 3);

//Rewrite

function mycustomname_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule('jobs/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=listings&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init');
```

Comment: WordPress will append a number to the slug automatically if the same title is used twice. Is there a reason you can't just rely on that, and need the post ID?

Comment: what jacob is saying. if you post multiple articles with the same title, the slug will get automagically extended by dash number, so you have "title", "title-2", "title-3"... no matter if it is custom post type or post or page or taxonomy...

Comment: The slug is always unique.

Comment: Thank you Jacab, Honk31 and Ahmad. I was trying to create some uniformity to the slug. Using the post_Id would allow a good reference rather than -1, -2 etc being used across all posts. By using the id, every post would have a unique id reference in the slug which relates to the post rather than just a -1, -2 which would be used across multiple posts when duplicated.

Comment: Rewriting URLs on the web server level, in my opinion, would be a better solution than intervention in the slug generation default process.